# O(n) time smallest spanning window combination of the elements in k sorted arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Is there a way to get, in `O(n)` time, the combination of the elements in `k` sorted arrays which gives me the smallest difference between the minimum and maximum elements in the combination? `n` is the total number of elements in those arrays.

Here is an example:

```
array1 = [11]
array2 = [5,7]
array3 = [6,18]
```

And for those arrays, below are all possible combinations:

```
comb1 = [11, 5, 6]
comb2 = [11, 7, 6]
comb3 = [11, 5, 18]
comb4 = [11, 7, 18]
```

In this case, the differences of the minimum and maximum elements are `6, 5, 13, 11` respectively for the above combinations. So, what I should return is `comb2`, since the difference for that combination is the smallest.

In case it helps, there are no repeating elements in the entire set of values in the original arrays.

Comment: In general, for problems of the form "find the minimum value of [thing]" or "find the maximum value of [thing]", going through every possible [thing] tends to be a horrible solution.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense! I was just curious whether getting all combinations was possible in linear time, although I did not expect it to be possible. Based on @maraca's comment above, I changed the question such that it reflects my ultimate goal, which might be possible in linear time.

Comment: I could do that in O( n * log k ) if that'll work for you, but I don't have a linear time solution.

Comment: Depends on whether `k` is constant. If `k` is some small or constant number, `k*n` or `(logk)*n` is still `O(n)`.

Comment: I think k is not considered constant or small enough, it can be any number. It is possible that there is no O(n) solution. But still, @MattTimmermans I am curious of your solution! Could you explain it in a comment?

Comment: Put the smallest element from each array in a min heap.  Repeatedly remove the smallest element from the min heap and insert the next element from the same array.  At some point the heap will contain the selection of one element from each array that has the smallest max-min difference.  It's easy to keep track of this difference and remember the smallest value.

Comment: @MattTimmermans can you post an answer for the above algorithm, you solution seems valid, I am not able to work my head around it, it will be helpful for us. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Sort the numbers together, as well as each array separately :

```
a: 11
b: 5, 7
c: 6, 18

5,  6,  7, 11, 18
b1 c1  b2  a1  c2
```

For any choice we make *not* to remove an outer number (the right- or left-most), the next sequence of choices is clear. If we choose to fix `c2` (18), we can go up to `b2` from the left. But if we remove `c2`, the only change in the left-bound is within the `c` array itself.

Start with the most we can remove from the left for the fixed rightmost element. At any point, removing an element from the right *will only move the left-bound if the element is one of the last two in any one array*. Keep removing the rightmost element, each time updating the left-bound if needed. Pick the best seen interval. (Note that the elements between the outer two elements do not matter, we can pick any one from each array as a representative.)

Complexity of the sliding window iteration after sorting is `O(n)` since with sorted arrays, the cumulative left-bound updates are `O(n)`.

Comment: AFAIK merging k arrays of in total n elements is in `O(n log k)`, which is pretty good but unfortunately not `O(n)`

Comment: @le_m that's why I explicitly explained that the O(n) section of the algorithm is after the sorts are done. (See the end of my answer.)

Comment: For me, it was not clear from reading your answer whether you present an `O(n)` answer as was asked for by OP or not. Since you don't mention the overall complexity, I added it as a comment, that's all (I actually think the algorithm you describe is pretty elegant).

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** I don't think that this is possible to do in `O(n)` (though I cannot prove it), so below you can find two `O(n*logk)` solutions.

**Solution 1:**
Use min-heap of size `k` as described [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-smallest-range-containing-elements-from-k-lists/).

**Solution 2** (mine)

We need 3 additional arrays, let's call them `A`, `B` and `C`. Let's also call the input arrays "original arrays".

- `A` will have size `n` and will keep all elements from all original arrays in sorted order
- `B` will also have size `n` and will keep information about the source of the elements in the array `A`, i.e. from which original array element in `A` comes from
- `C` will have size `k` and it will contain last seen indices of elements from the original arrays during the process (see below)

Because the original arrays are sorted, we can create arrays `A` and `B` in `O(n*logk)` time by using [k-way merge algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm) (one example is with min-heap: at the beginning put first elements of all original arrays in min heap; then iteratively pop the smallest element from the min heap, put in `B`, and push the next element from the same original array in heap). So, for the example you provided, arrays `A` and `B` will look like this: `A = [5, 6, 7, 11, 18], B = [1, 2, 1, 0, 2]` (`5` comes from second original array, `6` comes from third original array etc.).

Now we use [sliding windows technique](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/window-sliding-technique/) to find the window of size at least `k` whose difference between last and first element is the smallest. The idea is to iterate through array `B` until we "collect" elements from **all** original arrays - it means that we found a combination, and now just check the difference between the first and last element of that combination. Array `C` now comes in the game - we initialize all its elements with -1, and set `C[i]` to last index of any element from the original array `i`. Once we find first sliding window that contains elements from all original arrays, we further extend that window to the right and shrink from the left while keeping the property that representatives from all original arrays are inside the window. So, algorithm will look like this:

```
// create arrays A and B, initialize array C
int collected = 0;
int min_idx = 0;
int result = INT_MAX;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    bool check_result = false;
    if (C[B[i]] == -1) {
        ++collected;
        check_result = true;
    }
    C[B[i]] = i;
    while (min_idx < C[B[min_idx]] && min_idx < i) {
        check_result = true;
        ++min_idx;   
    }
    if (collected < k) continue;
    if (check_result && result > (A[i] - A[min_idx]))
        result = (A[i] - A[min_idx]);
}
return result;
```

Let's explain it through your example:

```
A = [5, 6, 7, 11, 18]
B = [1, 2, 1, 0, 2]
C = [-1, -1, -1]

i = 0 // state after step 0, we have seen element from array 1
min_idx = 0      
C = [-1, 0, -1]
collected = 1
result = INT_MAX

i = 1 // we have seen element from array 2
min_idx = 0    
C = [-1, 0, 1]
collected = 2
result = INT_MAX

i = 2 // again element from array 1, increase min_idx
min_idx = 1    
C = [-1, 2, 1]
collected = 2
result = INT_MAX

i = 3 // element from array 0, window is full, update result
min_idx = 1
C = [3, 2, 1]
collected = 3
result = 5

i = 4 // again element from array 2, increase min_idx and compare with result -> it is bigger, so don't update result
min_idx = 2
C = [3, 2, 4]
collected = 3
result = 5
```

Time complexity is `O(n*logk)` because creating arrays `A` and `B` from `k` sorted arrays takes `O(n*logk)`, and during the loop each of `n` elements is checked at most twice so this part is `O(n)` and finally `O(n*logk + n) = O(n*logk)`. If you merge original arrays into one, this is [the best you can get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm#Lower_Running_Time_Bound):

> One can show that no comparison-based k-way merge algorithm exists
>   with a running time in O(n f(k)) where f grows asymptotically slower
>   than a logarithm.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's not O(n) if you need to sort.

Comment: @גלעדברקן You are right, originally I thought that we can sort it linearly because input arrays are sorted.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Your solution looks similar, can you add its complexity?

Comment: Can your algorithm be O(n log k) if the original arrays are not each pre-sorted?

Comment: @גלעד ברקן Then it is O(k * s * log s), where s is the length of the longest original array, and this is less than O(n logn). Btw, both your last comment and upvote disappeared.

Comment: Sorry, it's because I misunderstood your algorithm :) I need to learn more about sorting complexity in general. But I suppose in terms of just the sorting both our algorithms seem to require similar preprocessing.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I have extended my answer, `O(n*logk)` is actually the best we can get if we merge k sorted arrays into one.

Comment: Are you sure? This post lists O(nk log k) for merging k arrays: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-arrays/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163656/discussion-between-miljen-mikic-and--).